# How to get size of transmission using urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I have the basic code (form https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.voidspace.org.uk')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

I would like to get the of the entire request and the size of the entire response, Is there any way? 
(haven't seen one for urllib2 or for requests)

"entire" - means including headers and any meta-data that might be sent with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`res.headers` might or might not contain a field provided by the server which says `content-length`. So `int(res.headers['content-length'])` will give you the information - if the server provides it.

A very simple implementation of a HTTP stream might not provide this information at all, so you don't know it until you get EOF.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with `content-length` is that it doesn't include headers, cookies etc which might be significant.